# Instagram relationship endpoint that modify the relationship with target user

Tags: ios, rest, instagram-api

I'm developing an app that uses instagram API, when I'm trying to follow or doing other action to another user programmatically with POST method

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

the response is

```
This action is invalid. Please supply a valid action from the following: follow, unfollow, approve, ignore, block, unblock
```

P.S:

- the other user already added in sandbox mode
- scope used are : [.basic,.followerList,.publicContent,.relationships] and access tocken and user id are tested and valid
- I'm using this library https://github.com/AnderGoig/SwiftInstagram to avoid handling http requests and this library added the action parameter with 'follow' correctly with post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody face the problem, the solution is to send the action parameter in the body not in url, I'm using the library like I said so I thought it's ok but when testing it with postman and send the parameter in body it returns the result as expected